# Timing specifications for LCD module

Tags: vhdl, lcd, quartus

I'm writing a VHDL code for a [TFT LCD 7" screen by terasic](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive_download.pl?Language=Taiwan&No=670&FID=d29502a32e93378ab3ffb89a416b81a1) and I'm having a hard time understand the timing specifications presented in the [datasheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/osyb78wiee9r9uv/big-LCD.pdf?dl=0)

- **page 17, table 3-1** in manual (download-link)
- **page 15, section 8.3** in datasheet (dropbox-link)

I've found at a computer in my office a VHDL code ment for the same LCD screen and the guy who wrote it isn't availble. The most interesting part but yet not fully clear of the code he wrote is presented:

```
process(Reset,clk_33)
begin   
    if Reset = '0' then
        H_count <= 0;
        V_count <= 0;
        DE <= '0';
        LCD_fin <= '0';
        
        R<=(others=>'0');
        G<=(others=>'0');
        B<=(others=>'0');
        
    elsif rising_edge(clk_33) then
        H_count <= H_count + 1;  -- Horizantal pixels count
        case V_count is -- Vertical row
            when 0 to 12 => V_sync <= '0'; LCD_fin <= '0'; -- Vertical pulse width
            when 13 to 22 => V_sync <= '1'; -- Vertical back porch
            when 23 to 502 =>  V_sync <= '1'; -- Vertical valid
            when 503 to 523 =>  V_sync <= '1'; LCD_fin <= '1';  -- Vertical front porch
            when 524 => V_count <= 0; 
        end case;
        case H_count is -- Horizontal column
            when 0 to 29 => H_sync <= '0';  -- Horizontal pulse width
            when 30 to 45 => H_sync <= '1'; -- Horizontal back porch
            when 46 to 845 => H_sync <= '1'; DE<='1'; -- Horizontal valid
            when 846 to 1054 => H_sync <= '1'; DE<='0';-- Horizontal front porch
            when 1055 => H_count <= 0; V_count <= V_count + 1;
        end case;
```

I know VHDL pretty good but I can't seem to find a good explenation for the items:

> HSYNC/VSYNC setup/hold time[ns]
>
> Horzontal/Vertical pulse width

In addition, do you have any idea why would there be 2 operation modes(DE/SYNC)? And when should I use each one? Modules for other types of screens such as VGA are much simpler..
My boss is pushing me hard on this task because I'm working on this for a month now. If somebody here will have a nice definition of these time parameters I will be more than happy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### definitions:

> HSYNC/VSYNC setup/hold time[ns]

That's the minimal amount of time needed for the 33[mhz] DCLK to rise from '1' to '0' and vise versa.

> Horzontal/Vertical pulse width

For LCD_HSD for example, that's the amount of DCLK's pulses in which LCD_HSD is high as '[tollin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4119950/tollin)' mentioned. And the same for LCD_VSD for LCD_HSD as DCLK.
I've uploaded a repository to [github](https://github.com) with an LCD-driver quartus project that creates a comfortable generic module for everyone to use:
https://github.com/Doron-Behar/VEEK-MT_LCD-driver

Answer (score 0):

HSYNC or horizontal sync signal is a single short pulse which indicates the start of every line.
Similarly VSYNC or Vertical sync signal is a single short pulse which indicates the start of every frame.

Pulse width is the time for which each signal is at logic high state. In your example HSYNC is logic high from 13ns to 523ns. That means 510ns is the pulse width of HSYNC

Comment: And what about "pulse width"?

Comment: Do you know why are there 2 operation modes(DE/SYNC) Should I use both of them?